# Angular cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't quite figure out why the following isn't working:

main.html

```
<div class="MainCtrl">
  <h1>{{message.test}}</h1>
</div>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function(someService, $location, $scope) {

    $scope.message.test = "blablabla";

  }
});
```

When I run the code I can an error that states:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'test' of undefined
>       at new  (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/main.js:13:25)
>       at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4473:17)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4481:27)
>       at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9108:28
>       at $route.link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:977:26)
>       at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8746:9)
>       at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8246:11)
>       at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7637:13)
>       at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7512:30)
>       at name.$get.boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7656:16)

Clearly I'm missing something super obvious..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're defining a property to an **undefined** object, you have to initialized your object before setting properties.

```
$scope.message = {};
$scope.message.test = 'bla';
```

Answer (score 6):

You should initialize your `$scope.message` object, but do it safely (just in case it's defined somewhere else, maybe in some circumstanes):

```
$scope.message = $scope.message || {}; 
$scope.message.test = "blablabla";
```

Comment: even after 7 yrs you solution works for me. your last seen was 2 yrs ago. Where ever you're, i wish **you will find strength with each new day** .

Answer (score 4):

`message` in your code is not an object, you must make it:

```
$scope.message = { test: 'blablabla' };
```

Answer (score 2):

your test does not exist inside a message, you need to do `$scope.message = {};` before , `$scope.message.test = "blablabla";`